# How to free up the space after deleting an AVD in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I want to delete an AVD in AVD manager of android studio.

Before I delete it, it takes for example 4 GB of storage, and when I delete it, I don't get any free space in storage.

How do I get my space back after deleting an emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete Emulator’s Temp Files temp folder which located in this directory `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator .`

Answer (score 0):

In my pc, I had to delete the emulator I wanted in the following directory:
C:/Users/username/.android/avd