# How can I get free space back after deleting Android Studio emulators?

Tags: android, android-emulator

my emulators on Android Studio were buggy so I decided to reinstall them. Prior to deleting 2 emulators (they were about 11 and 9 GBs large) I took a screenshot of available space on my file manager, and after deleting them I noticed that the available space increased by 4.8 GBs, and not ~20 GBs. I checked the trash folder and ran a disk usage analysis, but couldn't see where the emulator files went if they weren't deleted.

My OS is Pop!_OS 20.04, my Android Studio version is 2021.1.1 Patch 2 (Flatpak version) and my ADB version is 1.0.39.

Edit: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63645284/how-to-free-up-the-space-after-deleting-an-avd-in-android-studio) weren't helpful, since I use Linux (and hence don't have an AppData folder) and the size of my ~/.android/avd directory is 12.5 KBs.

Answer (score 2):

Remove emulator files from AVD directory inside `~/.android/avd/`

- Open the AVD manager
- Right-click one of the devices
- Select "Show on Disk"

Comment: There is almost nothing under the `~/.android/avd/` directory, as I mentioned in the post, just small config files and empty folders (still I've deleted all of them). Since I've already deleted the emulators, I can't see them on the AVD manager.

Comment: Please try using ```rm -rf emulatorNameIWantToDelete.*``` &
please check any files there

Comment: Under which directory? There is nothing under `~/.android/avd/`.